# ADC Vref Options

Tags: voltage-reference

Looking to utilise vref on a K60 Kinetis, which has VREFH and VREFL pins. Ideally referencing to 3v3, but very stable -ie not using the supply lines - what would be the best way of achieving this - a dedicated VREF IC (and if so, what, and how would it be connected) or can a more simple yet elegant solution be proposed?

TIA.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-reference/693

Comment: How would a shunt be used? Just accross the VREF lines? Id apreciate more info please :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandgap_voltage_reference

Answer (score 1):

VREFH - VREFL minimum is 1.13V for Kinetis K60. Looks like VREFL must find its way to the chip's Vss (usually "ground") pin.
 VREFH *can be* as high as the chip's Vdd (3.3V in your case?) but no higher.

Yes, a dedicated band-gap reference chip is a good solution for applying a stable DC reference voltage to VREFH. Most require a little voltage headroom. If a Vdd of 3.3 V is applied to their input, reference output DC voltage must be a little less. A shunt regulator suggested by Trevor might require less overhead than some others. Some references allow you to adjust output voltage with an external resistor divider (circuit arrangement found in data sheets).
In the case below, a 2.5V reference chip provides the K60's analog-to-digital converter its DC reference voltage, fed from the less-regulated Vdd supply. Analog input voltages to an A-to-D input above 2.5V will render a result that is over-scale.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f43yUS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the reference cathode need not be supplied by Vdd. If you want VREFH to be very close (but not above) 3.3V, it could be supplied from a higher, unregulated voltage up to 30V. R1 would in that case be a larger value. You would then have to add a few precision resistors to the reference chip to boost its nominal 2.5V up toward 3.3V.

Comment: Could I use a 3v3 ref chip and then use the 5v rail, with say a 1.5k R?

Comment: @MattyT2017 Yes, but you'd run the risk of VREFH > Vdd. That may not be a problem, but you might want to check linearity for analog A-to-D input voltages near the top-end (close to 3.3V).